# Metaplex metadata program creator is verified without signing

Tags: metaplex, metadata, verification

In [this transaction](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/27X1C2EPSDV9fJAeCwvdY4w5NM44mzjYkPHQU2kD8cZCDduYvQrvbEnYmNA6ZEyA8yQXKeuUU2TXvaHkAuqeg8rB)
a metadata account is created in instruction 5.6. [(Parsed instruction)](https://solscan.io/tx/27X1C2EPSDV9fJAeCwvdY4w5NM44mzjYkPHQU2kD8cZCDduYvQrvbEnYmNA6ZEyA8yQXKeuUU2TXvaHkAuqeg8rB).

In the create metadata instruction from metaplex-metadata-program there is a loop over the creators array. A creator can only be verified if the creator's address is the updateAuthority address and if it signed the transaction [(source-code)](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/c7da0aa4decdb730a004b7527e4c233805f1a404/token-metadata/program/src/assertions/metadata.rs#L83).

But in the above transaction the first verified creator did not sign the transaction?
How is that possible? Does it have to do something with the fact that the first verified creator is a pda, as per the metaplex candy guard instruction?

Answer (score 2):

The metadata account is created with the first creator set to verified. (This is why you don't see a sign instruction).

Adding it as verified creator is possible since it (fXnX8Mj43U1TQoCSxQmgU5LXijqxcL7PCD9sL1nmhuM) is a PDA of your candy machine which is creating the account.

Comment: But looking at the source of the assert_data_valid function it seems like it will end at [this error line](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/c7da0aa4decdb730a004b7527e4c233805f1a404/token-metadata/program/src/assertions/metadata.rs#L106) since allow_direct_creator_writes is false (line 76) and the updateAuthority is not the signer (line 83). Or does update_authority_info.is_signer evaluate to true?